# STUN-TURN server ports range risks

Tags: ejabberd, stun, turn

I´m following a tutorial to setup a STUN/TURN server, but it´s asking me to open ports range  **49152 to 65535** in my public server.

Wouldn't leaving these ports open be a serious security risk to the server that would be vulnerable to attack?

Tutorial link:
www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-set-up-ejabberd-video-voice-calling/

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is genuine. I would recommend you to use some sort of packet filtering in your server or otherwise known as an Intrusion Detection System.

You can use Snort on your server to carry out the above task. If you're expecting a finite number of types of incoming packets in your server, I would recommend you go with whitelisting. Otherwise, you may go for blacklisting as well.

You can check out the following links for more info:

1. [Blacklists and Whitelists in Snort](https://sublimerobots.com/2015/12/the-snort-reputation-preprocessor/)
2. [Snort Documentation](https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/249/original/snort_manual.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20200613%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200613T051312Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=ad5c6b1f4472c32f84297856ac32af1a84a5a166ab54b9e0a7ff0947fca59a71) It's a bit lengthy, but it will give you a more comprehensive understanding about Snort.
3. [Official Site](https://www.snort.org/)